# Write CSV without deflate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a csv on HDFS , however I am getting a .deflate extention as an output . Is there a way that I can write csv with just .csv extention using pyspark. I did try compression=None but it didn't work.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.parquet(<<path>>)

df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "false") \
    .mode('overwrite') \
    .csv(output + '/' + end_date , compression=None)
```

any help  will be appreciated.

Thanks
Sumit

Comment: the option is case sensitive. Have you try `compression=none`

Answer (score 1):

adding following spark conf worked for me.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config("mapred.output.compress", "false").getOrCreate()
```